# Combining two different datasets for machine learning

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

I have two datasets. The first one is traffic data. Columns represent nodes (traffic sensors locations) and index is time. Values inside are the corresponding spatio-temporal speed values. Looks something like this:

```
In [1]: speed_matrix
Out[1]:
Time                   node1  node2  node3
2015-01-01 00:00:00       55     45     60  
2015-01-01 00:10:00       57     48     58
2015-01-01 00:20:00       56     50     60
```

The second dataset is weather data that has time and weather conditions. Looks like this:

```
In [2]: weather_data
Out[2]:
Time                   temperature  humidity  windspeed
2015-01-01 00:00:00             10        71        0.0  
2015-01-01 00:10:00             10        71        0.0 
2015-01-01 00:20:00             11        70        0.0
```

I am using these datasets to predict traffic using GraphConvolutionalLSTM class from [here](https://github.com/zhiyongc/Graph_Convolutional_LSTM/blob/master/Code_V2/HGC_LSTM%20%26%20Experiments.ipynb) (as well as PrepareDataset, TestModel and TrainModel classes).

I want to somehow combine the two datasets and **test whether predicting traffic with additional weather data can improve the accuracy of predictions**. The model I am using for prediction works fine for the speed_matrix, but I don't know **how to add the weather data**. Should I somehow fuse the datasets into a single dataset? Or make changes to the model?

I tried to simply merge the two dataframes like this:

```
In [3]: merged data
Out[3]:
Time                   node1  node2  node3  temperature  humidity  windspeed
2015-01-01 00:00:00       55     45     60           10        71        0.0 
2015-01-01 00:10:00       57     48     58           10        71        0.0
2015-01-01 00:20:00       56     50     60           11        70        0.0
```

But when running the code I get an error:

```
RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (40x331 and 323x323)
```

I am not sure what mat1 and mat2 are exactly.

Comment: This might be a better question for [datascience.se]

Answer (score 0):

Just join the 2 Data Frames. They will be aligned based on the indexes:

```py
merged_data = speed_matrix.join(weather_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

merge is the key here:

```
import pandas
dfinal = speed_matrix.merge(weather_data, on="Time", how = 'inner')
```